# What is the difference between DataFrame.cache() and hiveContext.cacheTable?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Is there any difference between the following snippets:

```
val df = hiveContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df.registerTempTable("myTable")
df.cache()
```

and

```
val df = hiveContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
df.registerTempTable("myTable")
hiveContext.cacheTable("myTable")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. HiveContext class [extends SQLContext class (source code)](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.scala#L90), so they share the same `cacheManager`. In fact, HiveContext does not have a `cacheTable` function at all (it invokes the SQLContext's `cacheTable` function)

**Edit**: Calling `df.cache()` translates to invoking `persist`, which translates as `sqlContext.cacheManager.cacheQuery(this)`, as evidenced in the [source code for DataFrame](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala#L1593)

while `sqlContext.cacheTable` also translates as `sqlContext.cacheManager.cacheQuery`[source code for SQLContext](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L355)